# How to produce a table with a certain width and many columns

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

I want a table, 16.5cm width with 37 columns and numbers 1-36 centred like in typical project management charts. I tried several things but something doesn’t work. If I use only a couple of columns everything is fine. But increasing the number doesn’t give a proper result. I’d be also happy with a \documentclass{standalone} solution that I could shrink down to 16.5cm manually then. The textsize will probably be a problem then if the column separation is to big.

There will be text int he first column, nothing in the other ones. I know that the table is now wider than textwidth but usepackage{geometry} won’t solve the problem, so I left it out. The Ganntpackage is a great suggestion but I’ll have to mimic a boring excel sheet at least vaguely.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphics}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\resizebox{16.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{3cm}|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|@{}}
Test &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&33&34&35&36\\
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will there be something else inside of the columns or just the numbers?  Since you mentioned "project management", you might probably want to have a look at the `pgfgantt` package.

Comment: Why the combination of a `\textwidth`-wide `tabularx` that you then scale to a width of 16.5cm? Why not use `\begin{tabularx}{16.5cm}` in the first place?

Comment: Are you aware, that 16.5cm is wider than the current textwidth?

Comment: (1) Remove the `\resisebox`  (2) set \tabcolsep  to `0pt` or nearly,  and (3) use  `\tiny` font size (suggestion: left `\textwidth` as width of the table, relative lengths are always better)